# How to configure the android intent actions in android manifest

Tags: android, android-intent, android-webview, intentfilter

I have a webview in my app, on trying to do actions like making a call (Tapping call button from results displayed in webview), sending mails and other actions, my webview doesn't perform those actions

I Found a solution to add the intent actions in my web view activity as

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(intent)
```

Instead of doing so is there any way to add in the android manifest file
or Is there any way to turn on all of the intent actions for the webview so that
there wont be further issues in handling the actions

Can someone help me on this pls

Answer (score 1):

Your answer seems to me a bit strange, I think you are a bit confuse about the difference between `Intent` and `manifest permission`. The first one are the system used by android to let app communicate with each other, the second one allow you to use some feature of the device like wifi and direct phone call that need the explicit agreement of the user to be used (the prompt that popup when you make the first install of an app).

With this clarification it is clear that if you want to do something that require another app you will have to make an `Intent`. This `Intent`, if well formed, will be elaborated by the os that will take care of sending it to the correct application able to accomplish the `Intent`requirement.

**So the answer to your question, as far as i know, is no, you have to use intent if you have the need of calling external app.** It's also a good practice to set in the manifest only the permission really needed by the app, this way the user know what the app really can do and  and what it can't do.

Hope i understand your question and answer it.